# getFilesDir() in a subclass to View

Tags: java, android, view, getfiles

Can I use the method `getFilesDir()` in a .class that use `extends View`?

```
public void save(){
    try {
        File myDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myDir + "/Test.txt");
        fw.write(Integer.toString(score));
        fw.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

just the method `getFilesDir()` gets a error message with one quick fix available - create method `getFilesDir()`. And this is because it's in a class with extends View, I can fix this by putting the method in an Activity class and use the method in the View class by using static. This don't work ether, the program crash and the score doesn't get saved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass the Context in to your View constructor and you'll be able to get the sdcard location.

[Edit]
What I mean is that this class of yours that extends View probably doesn't exist anywhere where it has access to the context natively so you need to pass it that object in the constructor FROM when you instantiate it in your Activity (where you DO have a reference to it).

so something like this...

```
class Foo extends View{
   public foo (Context c){
      c.getFilesDir(); // or any method that belongs to context
   }
}
```

then in your Activity

```
class Main extends Activity{
   @override
   public void onCreate(){
       super.onCreate();


       Foo foo = new Foo(this); //this is a reference to the activity AND is also the context;
   }
}
```

Comment: What he is saying is that after someone answers your question and the answer works for you, click the green check next to the answer. And go into your profile and do the same for all your questions.

Comment: And the answer isn't give any help, even if i use   myDir = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()); in the constructur, it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

use the getContext method

```
 getContext().getFilesDir();
```

Comment: btw you should just use the File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(),"Test.txt"); version of the file class and simply use new FileWriter(file); also make sure you flush() your filewriter.